# How to query/filter cells against single values when cells have multiple values?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file that follows the following format

| Columns one | Column two |
| --- | --- |
| Key1 | Value1,Value2,value3 |
| Key2 | value5 |

I can easily use a list and `.isin` to filter the data-frame as follows:

```
list_keep = ['Value5']

dataframe[dataframe.isin(list_keep).any(axis=1)]
```

Which gives me the second row, but if there are cells with multiple values (like in the first row in the example table above with the `Value1,Value2,value3)` then the isin filters no longer works for single values like just `value1`. This makes sense since the `""` is turning them into a single string which I missed because spreadsheets remove the `""`.

For example,When I do this

```
list_keep = ['Value1']

dataframe[dataframe.isin(list_keep).any(axis=1)]
```

Then the nothing  is returned because the first row has `Value1,Value2,value3`  as one single string. (or the first row is not produced as output as the desired outcome).

IMPORTANT NOTE: I want to query all columns not just one.

So, how can I set this code up such I can query multiple elements with cells?

Is there a way to do this in pandas?

Comment: Do you want to query the values in `list_keep` against `column two` only?

Comment: All columns. Sorry! forgot such an important detail. I will edit it to add that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `Stack` the dataframe to reshape, then `split` and `explode` the strings and use `isin` to test for occurrence of strings in `list_keep`, then `groupby` on `level=0` and reduce with `any` to create a boolean mask:

```
mask = df.stack().str.split(',').explode().isin(list_keep).groupby(level=0).any()
```

Alternative approach with `applymap` and `set` operations:

```
mask = df.applymap(lambda s: not set(s.split(',')).isdisjoint(list_keep)).any(1)
```

---

```
>>> df[mask]

  Columns one            Column two
0        Key1  Value1,Value2,value3
```

Comment: This was the correct answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: This did not initially work for me because of extraneous white-spaces .For whatever reason, python's `csv` module's `.to_csv` function adds extra spaces before strings. A quick and easy way to remove these extra white spaces in Linux is to use this bash oneliner `sed -r 's/\s+//g'` then this code worked like a charm.